# How to create an array (and perform push, remove and show its elements) in Angular 2?

Tags: typescript

I have tried searching the tutorials/articles, and the threads on Stack Overflow, but nothing seem to cover the arrays in AngularJS 2, and how it differs from AngularJS 1. I need to create the arrays of the following class:

```
class User {
    FirstName:string;
    LastName:string;
}
```

And then, I want to create the event functions that add, remove and show the contents of the array. I need code examples for initializing the array, pushing elements into it, removing the specific (or last) element, and showing the contents of the array through iterations (alert() will be used).

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: What have you tried? `new Array(); `array.push()` ... there is nothing Angular2 specific

Comment: @SefaÜmitOray Yes, I am using TypeScript.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have tried those syntax that seems similar to JS1 syntax, but it doesn't seem to work. No errors are shown on the console of the server (using "npm start").

Comment: Your question doesn't provide any information that allows to make conclusions. Please provide more information.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have a file called "app.component.ts". In it, there are two classes: User (that you can see in the OP) and AppComponent (which I am bootstrapping in "main.ts"). I have another file "app.component.html" that has the form code (which works fine).. this file is referred in "app.component.ts", nothing complex. Now, I need to do/create binding/event functions that perform the operations on arrays, but I also need to create the arrays first. I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Can you reproduce in Plunker? I can't make any sense from your comment. See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Here you go (http://embed.plnkr.co/oX6fX4R8KNR4TqkCQEPR/). You can see that I have a class "User" in it.

Comment: `users: Array<User>;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use simple `javascript array function`  to add and remove item in array. I have an Sample example in which on checkbox click I add and remove item from array like:

Html Code :

```
<div *ngFor="let tvalue of typeArr; let i=index;" class="checkbox">
  <label class="text-capitalize">
  <input formControlName="value" type="checkbox" class="styled"
                         (click)="addtoarray('type',tvalue)"/>
    {{ tvalue }}
  </label>
</div>
```

In component file:

```
   public typeArr:Array<any> = ['angular2','Php','MySql','Java'];    
   public filterlist;

   addtoarray(key, value) {
     if (typeof this.filterlist == 'undefined') {  //check list 
       this.filterlist = {};
     }
    let dimensions = this.filterlist;
    dimensions[key] = dimensions[key] || [];  //initialize array

    let i = dimensions[key].indexOf(value);
    if (i != -1) {
     dimensions[key].splice(i, 1);   //remove array element
    }
    else {
     dimensions[key].push(value);    //insert array element
    }

    if (dimensions[key].length == 0) {
     delete dimensions[key];        //delete array
   }
   this.filterlist = dimensions;     
   alert(JSON.stringify(this.filterlist));
 }
```